# Sum of range and kernel of normal linear transformation is a direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products, direct-sum

If $V$ is a finite dimensional inner product space over $\mathbb{C^{n}}$ and $T:V\rightarrow V$ is a normal linear transformation, how can I show that $V=\operatorname{ran}\left(T\right)\oplus\ker\left(T\right)$, using the fact that $\operatorname{ran}\left(T\right)^{\perp}=\ker\left(T^{\ast}\right)$, where $T^{\ast}$ is the adjoint of $T$?

Here is what I have done so far. Let $x\in\operatorname{ran}\left(T\right)\cap\ker\left(T\right)$. Since $T$ is normal, then
\begin{align*}
&Tx=0\\
\implies&T^{\ast}Tx=0\\
\implies&T^{\ast}Tx=Tx\\
\implies&TT^{\ast}x=Tx.
\end{align*}
This gives us that $\left\langle x,Tx\right\rangle=\left\langle x,TT^{\ast}x\right\rangle=\left\langle T^{\ast}x,T^{\ast}x\right\rangle=0$. Thus, $T^{\ast}x=0$, so $x\in\ker\left(T^{\ast}\right)$.

Since $\operatorname{ran}\left(T\right)^{\perp}=\ker\left(T^{\ast}\right)$, then $\operatorname{ran}\left(T\right)=\ker\left(T^{\ast}\right)^{\perp}$. Thus, $\operatorname{ran}\left(T\right)\cap\ker\left(T\right)=\ker\left(T^{\ast}\right)^{\perp}\cap\ker\left(T\right)$, so $\left\langle x,y\right\rangle$ for all $y\in\ker\left(T^{\ast}\right)$. Since $x\in\ker\left(T^{\ast}\right)$, then $\left\langle x,x\right\rangle=0$, so $x=0$. Thus, $\operatorname{ran}\left(T\right)\cap\ker\left(T\right)=\left\{0\right\}$.

Now I'm just stuck on trying to show that $\operatorname{ran}\left(T\right)+\ker\left(T\right)=V$, and I'm not sure where to go.

Comment: rank-nullity formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note first (as you showed) that, for any $T$ (even if non-normal),
$$\tag1
\ker T=\ker T^*T.
$$
Indeed, if $Tx=0$, then $T^*Tx=0$. Conversely, if $T^*Tx=0$, then $$0=\langle x,T^*Tx\rangle=\langle Tx,Tx\rangle=\|Tx\|^2,$$ so $Tx=0$.

Using $(1)$ and that $T$ is normal, 
$$
\ker T=\ker T^*T=\ker TT^*=\ker T^*.
$$
Then
$$
(\ker T)^\perp=(\ker T^*)^\perp=\text{ran}\,(T). 
$$
The above shows that $\ker T$ and $\text{ran}\,T$ are the orthogonal complement of the other, so $V=\ker V\oplus \text{ran}\,T$.

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help :)